# Handle multiple gesture on UIWebView

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I have one web view. On which I have added left and right gesture to show previous and next page. When I zoom the content and scroll, it should not recognize left or right swipe. So I added following lines:

```
[swipeRight requireGestureRecognizerToFail:self.mWebView.scrollView.panGestureRecognizer];

[swipeLeft requireGestureRecognizerToFail:self.mWebView.scrollView.panGestureRecognizer];
```

In normal mode when I swipe left and right it is recognizing left and right gesture.
It is working fine.

But in zooming mode when user reaches the end of content and swipe it should recognize left and right swipe respectively.How to handle this scenario.Because when I swipe in zooming mode it fails to recognize left and right gesture.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use the UIGestureRecognizer method - gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:, just return no when user is zooming and not in the end of the content

Comment: I did not understand, can you please elaborate? How I will come to know whether user has zoomed and reached end of the content?

Comment: UIWebView has a scrollView, you can check its content offset, and use the scrollViewDelegate methods, it has some methods for managing zooming. I didn't really understand when you want to enable the swipe and when not to. You can elaborate on this and I can help you with some example code

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Its working fine. You can write it as answer, I will accept it.